# How can i cut an area of image before drawing to canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, canvas, html5-canvas

I am working on a canvas tool in which i will drag and drop images.
There is a large image which work like a background and then there will be another images which will be dragged.
But i need to cut some area of image so they can't override some area of previous image.

[image: Main image]

After image drag

[image: After image is dragged on canvas]

Please review the above link and help me how can we achieve this.

Regards
Aman

Comment: redraw the "clipped" part of the background onto the image ?

Comment: https://www.casetify.com/design/iphone
Look at the above url, that might clear you what i need.

Comment: Thanks @tamil, this is the clipped part

Comment: Well there are ways of clipping canvas, a quick search will give those to you, you could also use globalCompostieOperation over the dropped image on an other canvas, before drawing it back to your main one, but I still think that the easiest way for you here, is just to save the "should-not-be-covered" part in an other image, and always draw it last on your canvas.

Comment: @Kaiido did you have any example for that ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bk1eqLw2/ here the part you want to always keep is the blue star.

Comment: @Kaiido has it exactly right (and simple). Take the image into Photoshop (or your favorite image editor) and make everything transparent except your desired overlays. Don't crop the image so you don't have to worry about positioning. Then `drawImage` the overlay image last. Easy and simple! :-)

Comment: @Kaiido yes you are right but i need a implement a tool and i am very close  to implement it just this issue stuck me.
Anyways thank's for your suggestions.

Comment: Thanks Everyone i build that tool and it working like a charm :)